# VBA - Vlookup Multiple Columns and Fill to End of Range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do a Vlookup of an ID on the source sheet to a table in the data sheet. When the Vlookup is done, it needs to return the cell values from 6 different columns.

Here I have a function to get the range:

```
Function find_Col(header As String) As Range

    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range, def_Header As Range
    Dim col As Long, lRow As Long, defCol As Long
    Dim colName As String, defColName As String
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set y = Workbooks("Template.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = y.Sheets("Results")

    With ws1

        Set def_Header = Cells.Find(what:="ID", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set aCell = .Range("B2:Z2").Find(what:=header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

            defCol = def_Header.Column
            defColName = Split(.Cells(, defCol).Address, "$")(1)

            col = aCell.Column
            colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

            lRow = Range(defColName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

            Set myCol = Range(colName & "2")

            'This is your range
            Set find_Col = Range(myCol.Address & ":" & colName & lRow).Offset(1, 0)

        'If not found
        Else

            MsgBox "Column Not Found"

        End If

    End With

End Function
```

Then in my sub, I select the range and do a Vlookup which fills this range:

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],myTable,2,FALSE)"
```

And this works great.

Then I needed to return more than just one column, so I ended up with the formula:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = "=VLOOKUP($C3,myTable,{2,3,4,5,6},FALSE)"
```

**Source Sheet:**
[image]

**Data Sheet:**

[image]

So, my function returns only the range for one column, which I think I can use in terms of getting a row count then using something like this:

```
Set myRng = find_Col("Product")

For currentRow = myRng.Rows.count To 1 Step -1

Selection.FormulaArray = "=VLOOKUP($C3,myTable,{2,3,4,5,6},FALSE)"

Next currentRow
```

Then perhaps instead of `C3` it could look something like this:

`C & currentRow` --> `Selection.FormulaArray = "=VLOOKUP($C & currentRow,myTable,{2,3,4,5,6},FALSE)"`

But then I have the issue that only one cell is selected (G3) and from H-L is not. And I have no idea whether this is even a plausible effort.

Ideally of course, I would have cells `G3:L3` selected and fill the formula down to the last row.

My brain is just fried from all the thinking and attempts.

Comment: Isn't the output ending the same as the source table with all the data? If so... Why don't you just use a excel formula VLOOKUP+MATCH? `=VLOOKUP($B2,SHEETDATA!$B:$J,MATCH(G$2,SHEETDATA!$B$2:$J$2,0),0)`

Comment: Where do you use `currentRow` inside your `For...Next` statement?

Comment: @Damian Thank you for the reply.. I'm trying to avoid hard-coded cells as much as possible - in the event headers are shifted on the source sheet. Then also, the source sheet number of rows will not always bee the same as the data sheet, it is at the moment for the purpose of this demonstration.

Comment: @Pspl Than you for the reply. After the code with the `For Loop`, I included what the possible formula could look like.

Comment: If that is the case give me 10 minutes... The best way to do this (and fastest) is using dictionaries and arrays. @EitelDagnin are both sheets on the same workbook?

Comment: @SJR Thank you for the reply. I don't quite follow. Are you referring to past questions of mine perhaps?

Comment: @Damian Thank you very much, it will be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @SJR Once again, I do apologize. I had it as `find_Header` in the question at the end of the function. I have updated it to `find_Col`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this should do the trick... I've explained every instance but if you need help understanding just ask:

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillData1()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, arr As Variant, arrData As Variant
    Dim DictHeaders As Scripting.Dictionary, DictIds As Scripting.Dictionary, DictDataHeaders As Scripting.Dictionary, _
    DictDataIds As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Integer, i As Long, j As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets("Results")
        Set wsData = .Sheets("List")
    End With

    'Lets suppose your data always starts on row 2 in both sheets and column B will always have the max amount of rows filled
    With ws 'filling the first array
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        arr = .Range("B2", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Value
    End With

    With wsData 'filling the data array
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        arrData = .Range("A2", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Value
    End With

    'Now lets put everything into Dictionaries so if the data moves columns or rows won't matter
    Set DictHeaders = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DictIds = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 2) 'this will fill the headers positions on the main sheet
        If Not DictHeaders.Exists(arr(1, i)) Then DictHeaders.Add arr(1, i), i
    Next i
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1) 'this will fill the IDs positions on the main sheet
        If Not DictIds.Exists(arr(i, DictHeaders("KW ID"))) Then DictIds.Add arr(i, 1), i
    Next i

    Set DictDataHeaders = New Scripting.Dictionary
    Set DictDataIds = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrData, 2) 'this will fill the headers positions on the data sheet
        If Not DictDataHeaders.Exists(arrData(1, i)) Then DictDataHeaders.Add arrData(1, i), i
    Next i
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrData, 1) 'this will fill the IDs positions on the data sheet
        If Not DictDataIds.Exists(arrData(i, DictDataHeaders("KW ID"))) Then DictDataIds.Add arrData(i, DictDataHeaders("KW ID")), i
    Next i

    'Finally will loop through the main array to fill it with the data from the data array
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 6 To UBound(arr, 2) 'I'm assuming you want to avoid the first columns which are hidden
            arr(i, j) = arrData(DictDataIds(arr(i, 1)), DictDataHeaders(arr(1, j)))
        Next j
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    With ws 'filling the first array
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        .Range("B2", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Value = arr
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for this.. Looking promising! :) I have an error popping up on `Dim DictHeaders As Scripting.Dictionary`. This is the error `User Defined Type Not Defined`

Comment: Sorry! you need to check `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` on your libraries

Comment: Okay, I found the `Scripting Runtime` library now I am getting an error on this line: `Set DictIds = New Scripting` and the error is for `New Scripting`. The error message is `Expected user-defined type, not project`

Comment: You cant write that fast... Sorry, it's Scripting.Dictionary by the way, are there columns on the main sheet that won't on the data sheet?

Comment: Yes, there are 5 columns not visible in the question. These 5 columns appear on the source sheet but not on the data sheet.

Comment: Then there is no problem, as you could see the `j` starts on column 6, which is the first visible column on the main sheet. Did it work now?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am still stuck on the above error. I'm not sure if there's a reference I am missing... I cannot find anything called `Scripting.Dictionary`

Comment: `Set DictIds = New Scripting.Dictionary`

Comment: Haha oops.. Okay, ran it and now getting another error at this line `DictHeaders.Add arr(i, 1), i`. This is the error: `This key is already associated with an element of this collection`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189656/discussion-between-damian-and-eitel-dagnin).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got the true issue of your goal. However, since your `Selection` parts in your code should be avoid, why don't make something like the following?

```
Set myRng = find_Col("Product")

For currentRow = myRng.Rows.count To 1 Step -1

    Range(Cells(currentRow, 5), Cells(currentRow, 9)).FormulaArray = "=VLOOKUP(RC3,myTable,{2,3,4,5,6},FALSE)"

Next currentRow
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I am getting strange results. Please refer to my question as I have attached a screenshot of the results for your answer.

Comment: Toy have to adjust the formula yourself. For instance, don't you have to complete the `C3` cell address?? With the name of the sheet? The `#N/A` result simply means Excel isn't finding the text on the table.